# Condensing All Data into 1 row from 6 colums where a value is similar

Tags: sql, ms-access, transpose

Im hoping somebody can help me - im using MS Access 2019 to run a query. my raw data looks like this (Raw Data - 1):

[image: Raw Data - 1]

i have been able to run a Query to make that data appear like so (Ammended data - 2):
[image: Ammended Data - 2]

However im trying to make my data look like this :[image: Required Data Appearance]

i have tried everything i know but feel it is unfortunately a little beyond my skill set. The MS Access SQL i am using to get from image 1 to 2 is:

```
SELECT Data_Extractions.[Part&Des], 
IIf([Feature Descritpion]="Socket colour",[Feature],"") AS [Socket Colour], 
IIf([Feature Descritpion]="Supplementary Article/Info 2",[Feature],"") AS [Supplementary Article/Info 2], 
IIf([Feature Descritpion]="Sensor Type",[Feature],"") AS [Sensor Type], 
IIf([Feature Descritpion]="Connector Shape",[Feature],"") AS [Connector Shape], 
Replace(IIf([Feature Descritpion]="Fitting Depth [mm]",[Feature],"-") & "mm","-mm","") AS [Fitting Depth], 
Replace(IIf([Feature Descritpion]="Cable Length [mm]",[Feature],"-") & "mm","-mm","") AS [Cable Length]
FROM Data_Extractions
WHERE (((Data_Extractions.[Part&Des]) Like "VOL40001ABS") AND ((Data_Extractions.Suppl) Like "VXP"));
```

in an attempt to "Transpose the data" - essentially the Part number is the common denominator i believe.

any help would be fantastic!!

Cheer
Sam

Answer (score 2):

Really nothing extraordinary about your desired output. Two query methods.

1. Explore CROSSTAB query using First() function. Query in design view, select CROSSTAB from Design tab. Or use CROSSTAB wizard on Create tab.
2. Or use the query you started with and aggregate the records. This would be a GROUP BY (totals) query. Query in design view, click Totals button on ribbon. GROUP BY under Part&Des field and select Max operation under each calculated field.

Strongly advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in naming convention.

Also `Descritpion` is a misspelling of `Description`.